# lxml and incorrect source encoding

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, lxml

the following web page is not properly encoded, but I am building a client that needs to treat it properly anyway (no control on the server). Apparently the server is not providing UTF-8. How can I correct this using lxml and requests to have the result properly encoded ?

```
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
import requests

url = 'https://immobilier-segre.nestenn.com/maison-de-plain-pied-de-97-m2-plein-centre-de-segre-ref-33659881'
r = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)

with open('file.html', 'wb') as file:
    #write the pretty XML to a file
    file.write(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```

On this URL, this gives "FranchisÃ©" instead of "Franchisé". I do not have a problem if the url points to a site that is properly encoded, but with the upper url I have a problem and I would like to correct this on the client side to save my html file in correct encoding in all situations.

My guess is that the page is not properly encoded on the server side, and would like to detect and correct that on the client side.

Comment: Encoding is not correct. It displays "FranchisÃ©" instead of "Franchisé"

Comment: Why are you trying to parse `r.content` (which is binary) instead of `r.text`? Your example renders just fine on my system in the latter case, while I do see encoding problems in the former.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. I was looking in the lxml api for an answer... using r.text did provide me with what I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to parse r.content (which is binary) instead of r.text? Your example renders just fine on my system in the latter case, while I do see encoding problems in the former. – Eli Korvigo Nov 27 at 11:16